# Can I recover a deleted video from the iPhone 4S camera roll?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, data-recovery

So I blundered this morning. Had a cute video of my daughter on Easter, then I accidentally deleted when I was trying to show people (its amazing how a simple finger swipe can cause so much damage!).

Sadly, I didn't not do any sync to iTunes after this files was created, so no luck on that kind of backup.

So now I'm looking some type of file recovery software for an iPhone 4S. I've tried Tenorshare, Wunderphone, and a few others that have popped up on my Google searches (I'm really grateful for virtual machines for testing these out!).

These have not done me any good. Any ideas on what may be out there?

Answer (score 1):

If it is jailbroken and you have OpenSSH installed, you might be able to pipe a whole disk image to your computer, on which you will be able to try standard HFS+ file recovery software.

If you don't meet the above requirements, keep in mind all disk activity - especially that involved in the jailbreaking process, but even that which could have happened in the meantime by normal use, has the very potential of contributing to the overwriting of the affected files.

Comment: Saddly, not jail broken or that would have been a great option!